# Vimeo video not playing in chrome browser. it works in Firefox and Edge. using popcornjs

Tags: google-chrome, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, popcornjs

I have video play functionality in my application using Vimeo video and popcornjs. But from past few months it does not works in chrome browser. it is working in Firefox and Microsoft Edge browser.

while clicking on play button in chrome, At last its calling the **Pause event** . it should not call the **Pause event**. I am not able to find why **pause event** is firing after clicking play button.

in other browsers its working fine and **play event** is firing correctly.

is there any policy changes in chrome?